# A point $x$ belongs to closure of linear span if(f) every bounded linear functional that vanishes on the subset $\{ x_k\}$ vanishes at $x$?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

A point $x$ belongs to closure of linear span $\overline{<x_k>}$ if(f) every bounded linear functional that vanishes on the subset $\{ x_k\}$ vanishes at $x$?

I.e. if

$$l(x_k)=0 \space \forall x_k \in <x_k>$$
implies
$$l(x)=0$$

Why is there a connection between vanishing at $\{x_k\}$ and belonging to the closure of linear span?

Or can one always draw such $l$ that one can assume that

$$l(x_k)=0 \space \forall x_k \in <x_k>$$

Perhaps it means that one takes a linear combination (a linear functional) on $x_k$ s and then sets all the coefficients to zero?

Answer (score 1):

The link is the Hahn Banach Theorem. Suppose $x$ is not in the closure of the linear span of $\{x_k\}$ (which I name $A$), then you can find a linear functional which is zero on $A$ and $1$ at $x$.

The other direction is very easy.

Comment: But isn't there a contradiction? You suppose $x$ is not in the span and then find $l$ such that $l(x_k)=0$, which one needs, rather than which should contradict. Then one cannot show that $x$ is in the closure?

Comment: To the proposer: Let $B$ be the vector subspace generated by $\{x\}\cup A.$  For every $y\in B$  there is a unique scalar $s$ and unique $a\in A$ such that $y=sx-a$.  Because $x\not\in A$ and $y=sx-a=s'x-a'  \implies (s-s')x=a-a'\in A\implies$ $ ((s=s'\land a=a')\lor (x=(a-a')/(s-s')\in A)$... So   $l(sx-a)=s$ is well-defined. Now $0<d(x,A)=\inf_{a\in A}\|x-a\|$ because $x\not \in \bar A=A.$  If $s\ne 0$ then $|l(sx-a)|/\|sx-a\|=|s|/\|sx-a\|=1/\|x-a/s\|\leq 1/d(x,A).$ And $ l=0 $ on $A.$  Therefore $l $ is bounded in norm on $B.$ By Hahn-Banach, $l$ extends to  the whole space.